# How to send notification to users of a mobile application from a server when an event happens, using ionic 3 and laravel 5.6

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, ionic3, angular6

I am building a school application that will connect parents to teachers, i am using **Ionic 3** and **Laravel 5.6**.

And i want to be able to send a notification to all parents, when for instance a teacher gives an assignment, when the teacher enters the assignment question and click on the send button, the question is save to the database, after then a notification should be sent to the mobile devices of all parents who's children are taking that subject.

I have done a lot of research on how to do this, on the Cordova Push Notification Plugin and Cordova Local Notification. I have followed a video tutorial that implements Firebase and Push Notification, and also One Signal and Push Notification. But i was still unable to achieve what i wanted.

If they are anymore materials out there, that could help me achieve this, I will be so grateful to have someone share it with me, or if anyone can help me out with is, I will be very happy.

Answer (score 1):

These are the other materials I found:

[The PHP Package repository](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel-notification-channels/ionic-push-notifications)

[Laravel Notification Channels](http://laravel-notification-channels.com/gcm/)

[Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-send-push-notification-in-Android-from-Laravel-backend-to-specific-user-I-have-college-or-school-users)

Please let your users know that using OneSignal's "free" service would allow the company to get users data and sell it to others.

Google's Firebase cloud messaging service is reliable but comes with a cost if you want many connections. See Firebase Pricing Plans.

I personally used fcm. It was not really a breeze implementing it on my thesis but it worked nicely. No need to make the app listen on background for incoming notifications then create a local notification, me not selling my users data, and not paying anything on the use of firebase's services. I used the free 300 dollars gift from google cloud to shoulder the expenses from the firebase spark plan.(free for 12 months)

A **warning** if you use the cordova plugins of fcm: If you have a cordova plugin that uses google's services it may come in conflict with the fcm plugins you listed above due to different versions used. It may need manual editing on the src plugins.

If you decide on using fcm, this [link](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ionic-native-with-firebase-fcm-push-notifications-ios-android/) might help you. 
The basic steps you have to do after you set up the needed environment is to

1. Get FCM token on platform.ready async.
2. Save it to firebase under the said user
3. Create a cloud function that will send notifications